# The value of $1+2\alpha+3\alpha^{2}+...+n\alpha^{n-1}$ for complex $\alpha$

Tags: complex-numbers

Compute the value of $$1+2\alpha+3\alpha^{2}+...+n\alpha^{n-1}$$ in the form of a complex number where $\alpha$ is a non-real complex $n^{th}$ root of unity.

---

The answer given is : $$-\frac{n}{2}-i\cdot\frac{n}{2}\cot\frac{r \pi}{n},\qquad r=1,2,\ldots,n-1.$$

I don't know how to solve it. Please help me.

Comment: Hint : isn't $nx^{n-1}$ the differential of $x^n$ ? (remark also that a non real complex nth root of unity can not be equal to1). hint 2 : sometimes, to compute $f(\alpha)$, it is simpler to compute $f(x)$.

Comment: @MikeTeX but still I couldn't proceed. Can you provide an answer?

Comment: Another hint : do you know the formula for the sum of the first terms of a geometric progression ? (google) And good luck !

Comment: Ohh yaa.....thanks a lot... I didn't think in that way... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with $f(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}x^k$
the sum we are looking for is $f'(\alpha)$ and we also know that for $x\neq 1$ we have

$$f(x)=\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$$

$$f'(x)=\frac{(n+1)x^n}{x-1}-\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{(x-1)^2}$$

Bearing in mind that $\alpha^n=1$ one has:

$$S=f'(\alpha)=\frac{n+1}{\alpha-1}-\frac{\alpha-1}{(\alpha-1)^2}=\frac{n}{\alpha-1}$$

$$\frac{1}{e^{\frac{2ik\pi}{n}}-1}=\frac{e^{-\frac{ik\pi}{n}}}{2i\sin{\frac{k\pi}{n}}}=-\frac{i}{2}\cot{\frac{k\pi}{n}}-\frac{1}{2}$$

And this is just one step away from the result you're looking for...

Comment: You're welcome ! Tough to do it on my iPhone without paper and no rendering of LaTeX

Comment: Nice.........:)